# Let T be the set of trees with vertex set ....

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let T be the set of trees with vertex set {1,2,3,...21} and define G to be the graph with V(G) = T and E(G) = {(T1,T2)} where | E(T1) ∩ E(T2) | = 19}, Find the order and the diameter of G and determine if it is connected.

If we know the vertex set goes upto 21, isnt the order 21? I'm not sure how to determine the diameter

Comment: No, the order of $G$ is the number of distinct trees with vertex set $\{1,\ldots,21\}$. HINT: [Cayley’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley's_formula).

Comment: So 21^19 is the order?

Comment: It is indeed. $\,$

Comment: "Determine if it is connected" seems kind of redundant, coming after "find the diameter".

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For the order of $G$ you’ll want [Cayley’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley's_formula): you’re looking for the number of trees on the set $\{1,2,\ldots,21\}$ of labelled vertices.

Every tree with $21$ vertices has $20$ edges, so trees $T_1$ and $T_2$ are connected by an edge if and only if each of them has exactly one edge that is not in the other. For example, if we were looking at trees on the vertex set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, the two shown below would be adjacent:

```
       1---2---3---4          1---2---3---4  
                   |              |  
                   5              5
```

Both have edges $\{1,2\},\{2,3\}$, and $\{3,4\}$; only the first has $\{4,5\}$, and only the second has $\{2,5\}$.

Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be distinct vertices of $G$, so that there is an edge $e\in E(T_1)\setminus E(T_2)$. Removing $e_1$ from $T_1$ leaves a forest of two trees, say $C_1$ and $C_2$.

- Show that $T_2$ must have an edge $e_2$ with one vertex in $C_1$ and the other in $C_2$.
- Show that removing $e_1$ from $T_1$ and then adding $e_2$ results in a vertex $T_3$ of $G$ adjacent to $T_1$, and that $|E(T_3)\setminus E(T_2)|=|E(T_1)\setminus E(T_2)|-1$.
- Conclude that the distance from $T_1$ to $T_2$ in $G$ is at most $|E(T_1)\setminus E(T_2)|$.
- Explain why the distance from $T_1$ to $T_2$ in $G$ cannot be any less than $|E(T_1)\setminus E(T_2)|$, and conclude that it’s equal to $|E(T_1)\setminus E(T_2)|$.
- Show that there are vertices $T_1$ and $T_2$ of $G$ that have no edges in common. What is the distance between them?

Answer (score 0):

First note that the statement $V(G) = T$ tells us that each vertex of $G$ *is* a tree.

Notice that a tree with $21$ vertices has $20$ edges. Thus, the condition $E(G) = \{T_1, T_2\}$ where $|E(T_1) \cap E(T_2)| = 19$ means that two trees are connected in $G$ if and only if they share all but one edge. Another way of saying this is that we can move through the graph of trees by removing an edge of one tree and putting an edge somewhere else (in a sense "moving" the edge we removed).

Suppose that $G$ is connected and consider the case of two trees $T_1, T_2$ that have no edges in common (it isn't too difficult to find two such trees). In order to go from $T_1$ to $T_2$, since none of the edges are in common, we need to move *all* of the edges in $T_1$ to the corresponding edges in $T_2$. Thus, we need to move all $20$ edges. Moving these edges, one at a time, generates a path of at least $20$ in $G$, thus $d(T_1, T_2) \geq 20$ and thus $\text{diam}(G) \geq 20$. I say at least $20$ because it may be the case that if we directly move the edges from $T_1$ to $T_2$, then we may inadvertently create a cycle or disconnect the tree along the way which is not allowed. Thus, we way need to take some additional steps in moving the edges in order to avoid creating a cycle.

If it can be shown that there is an order to directly move the edges from any two trees $T_1$ and $T_2$ without accidentally creating cycles or disconnecting the tree in the process, then it follows that $\text{diam}(G) = 20$. However, I am not sure at the moment whether or not this is always possible. Perhaps someone else could provide more insight or hopefully the OP can finish the problem from here.